# Book about a mathematician turned into a dragon

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I have been searching for a book about a mathematician who figures out some math problem that ends up putting his soul into the body of a black dragon. I have never read this book, but the person who told me about it does not know the title or the author. Can someone help me identify it?

Comment: You may need to offer more information for someone to work it out for you. Literally anything you know about the book can be helpful.

Comment: There's a pretty solid list of books where people turn into dragons. Maybe it's one of these; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScaledUp

Answer (score 10):

Could you be looking for The Dragon and the George by Gordon R. Dickson? The main character becomes trapped in the body of a black dragon after going through an astral projection machine.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/114936.The_Dragon_and_the_George

Comment: Elements of "The Dragon and the George" were also used in the animated film "Flight of Dragons", wherein a college student who excelled at math was accidentally put into the body of a dragon. He then had to defeat the evil sorcerer villain using logic & science vs. the sorceror's magic.

Comment: There's 10 books in Dickson's Dragon Knight series, of which The Dragon and the George is the first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Knight Protaganist is a mathematician: http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Dragon_Knight.html?id=FWRcl9wJfMoC

Answer (score 1):

That could perhaps be [*Tea With the Black Dragon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_with_the_Black_Dragon) by R A MacAvoy, although it's hard to be sure without more details.

Comment: Aside from the Dragon in the title, I see no match to the OP's description. It's more like the Dragon has become a man than vice-versa.